# How to build custom authorization url in auth0.js

Tags: javascript, auth0

auth0.js builds authorization URL as DOMAIN + /authirize.
I need: DOMAIN + /auth.

How to customize authorization URL?

```
      let webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
        clientID: clientId,
        domain: domain,
        redirectUri: tredirectUrl,
        responseType: responseType,
        scope: scope
      });

      webAuth.popup.authorize({
        redirectUri: redirectUrl
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible to have a custom authorization URL out of the box. What you can do is build out your own interface and then leverage the management api to create a custom login experience however you will still have to use the designated resources to complete the authentication transaction.

https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/

<sub>(Affiliation: I'm Community Lead at Auth0.)</sub>

Comment: hello, is this still impossible to do in 2022? i'm facing the same problem. thanks